# How to change the Foreground color of a button in a DataGrid depending on values from another column? WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid, foreground

For a project I need to set buttons foreground color depending on values returned from a database.


F.e. if the value == 1 the foreground needs to be green.

when the value == 0 it needs to have its original gray color.

**I have the following design for my buttons in my wpf DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Name="FavoriteButton" ... Foreground="#454545" Click="Button_Click">ButtonTextHere</Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Other columns are automatically generated by the DataGrid's ItemsSource.


I tried to declare a public button in the behind code of my DataGrid but could not reference the buttons name "FavoriteButton"

**This is what I was trying**

```
public partial class DataGridMain : UserControl
{
    public Button btn;

    public DataGridMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btn = FavoriteButton
    }
}
```

**I already have this code to loop through my DataGrid**

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRowView dr in MainGrid.ItemsSource)
{
    if (dr[9].ToString() == "1")
    {
        // here should come the action to actually
        // change the foreground color of the Button.                   
    }
    else
    {
        // Set original color
    }
}
```

If anyone knows a good way to handle this, I would be thankful if you shared your knowledge!

Comment: The simplest approach would be a datatrigger in a style.

Comment: @Andy Any example available? I'm new to WPF so things are still kinda fuzzy to me :-)

Comment: The style can go in your button markup. The button's datacontext is the row from itemssource. Add a column -  bool presumably. The datatrigger sets foreground conditionally to one brush. A setter in the style should set default brush. Don't set foreground on the button as a value because the style won't override a set value.  You should be able to find examples of datatriggers pretty easy. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720218/change-the-foreground-of-a-datagrid-cell

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `DataTrigger` to your `Button` like this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="FavoriteButton" Click="FavoriteButton_Click">ButtonTextHere
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#454545"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Moreover, it would nice to map your colors to different `StaticResource`shared to other UI components in order to let you changed it quickly painless if needed.

Answer (score -2):

Bind the foregroundcolor in your XAML to another color property, so you are able to change it in your code:

```
<Button x:Name="color" Foreground="Green" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

put this in your FavoriteButton:

```
Foreground="{Binding ElementName=color, Path=Foreground, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Now you can change the color like this:

```
color.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
```

I admit, that this is not a professional way, but it should work

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply! This kind of looks easy though very interesting. I will try this at once!. If it helps I'll mark this as answer!

Comment: This is defenitly a point in the good direction, but now its coloring all my buttons in the same color. this is what I got so far:
public void SetFavoriteColor()
        {
            foreach (DataRowView row in MainGrid.ItemsSource)
            {
                if (row.Row["Favorite"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    
                    favButton.Foreground = Brushes.Lime;
                }
                else
                {
                    favButton.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: Which is he doing? Binding or setting the brush?

Comment: Did you bind it to all your buttons? You should only bind it to those buttons, you want to change. If you want to change multiple buttons in a different color, you need a different binding for each one.